# Non-linear ODE of degree one (Riccati looking)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the solution to the one dimensional ODE
$$
f'(x)= 1- f^2(x)?
$$

Is there a simple classical technique to use?  This looks like a 1-dimensional differential Riccati equation to me, but this isn't my field...

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40076, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/947175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=1-y(x)^2$$ so $$\frac{dy}{1-y^2}=dx$$

Comment: So after integrating $y(x)=arctanh(x)$?  Or have I missed something...

Comment: $$y=\tanh(x+C)$$

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense... Thanks :)

Comment: Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks!  You too :)